# Tiny DOM builder

Tags: javascript, reinventing-the-wheel, dom

My goal was to create a tiny DOM builder library that made creating element trees less gross.

This is the syntax I decided on:

```
var foo = Builder.create('div', function(){
    //set attributes
    this.id = "foo-div";
    this.title = "Foo Div";

    //append a child node
    this.create('button', function(){

        //append a text node
        this.text('Click Me!');

        this.on('click', function(){
            this.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        });
    });
 });

 document.body.appendChild(foo);
```

The builder factory also binds the created element to the function so you can also work with the element without all of the magic:

```
Builder.create('div', function(element){
    element.style.color = '#ffffff';
});
```

Here is the implementation:

```
var Builder = function(el){
    //set root and element shortcuts
    this.root = el;

    //create a new element
    this.create = function(tag, func){
        var builder, property, obj = {};
        var el = document.createElement(tag);

        //setup new builder
        builder = new Builder(el);

        if(func != undefined){
            obj = new (this.attach(builder, func))(el);
        }

        //apply attributes
        for (property in obj){
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {

                //set name and value
                builder.set(property, obj[property]);    
            }
        }

        return this.append(el);
    };

    //set attribute
    this.set = function(name, value){

        //try setAttribute (from jquery source)
        if (typeof this.root.setAttribute !== "undefined") {
            if (value === false) {
                this.root.removeAttribute(name);
            } else {
                this.root.setAttribute(name, value === true ? name : value);
            }               
        }else{
            this.root[name] = value;
        }

        return this;        
    }

    //attach prototypes
    this.attach = function(builder, func){
        func.prototype.create = this.create.bind(builder);
        func.prototype.set = this.set.bind(builder);
        func.prototype.text = this.text.bind(builder);
        func.prototype.html = this.html.bind(builder);
        func.prototype.on = this.on.bind(builder);

        return func;
    };

    //append element
    this.append = function(el){
        if(this.root == null){
            return this.root = el;
        }

        return this.root.appendChild(el);
    };

    //append text node
    this.text = function(content){
        return this.append(document.createTextNode(content));
    };

    //append html
    this.html = function(content){
        this.root.innerHTML += content;
        return this.root.lastChild;
    };

    //events
    this.on = function (event, handler) {
        if(this.root.addEventListener){
            this.root.addEventListener(event, handler);
        }else{
            this.root.attachEvent('on' + event, function(){
                handler.call(this.root);
            });
        }
    }

};

/**
 * DOM Builder factory
 */
Builder.create = function(tag, func){
    return (new Builder()).create(tag, func);
};
```

Thoughts:

- I really like the syntax, but the way I bind the methods to the function feels gross.
- I also think having the methods (`this.create`, `this.html`, `this.text`, `this.on`) exist in the same space that the attributes do (`this.id`) could cause a problem down the road if there was a conflict between a method and an attribute name.
- Performance is good (better than jQuery) but I'm not sure about memory. Is this thing a nightmare for the garbage collector?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johndm/qcha8g7u/)

Comment: You're overwriting `el` inside the create function.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not getting the point of this.  You're creating a new way to create DOM sections with code?  It looks like a lot of code to me to create a few DOM elements with attributes.  I'd expect a lot more of a table/data driven approach if you're trying to really make things more compact and minimize the code.

Comment: FYI, it's rarely hard to beat jQuery for performance.  That is not its strength.  Can you beat a plain HTML string for performance?

Comment: @jfriend00 it's faster than creating nodes with an html string, but slower than cloning existing nodes. The only performance goal was to be practical.

Comment: @jfriend00 The point is to create a shorthand to fire up element trees with dynamic or conditional structure. Since it's just working with regular DOM objects, you would use this alongside another library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting,

I agree with your assessment that mentioned *the way I bind the methods to the function feels gross.*

I forked your demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/konijn_gmail_com/hz62smvp/ 
and replaced

```
    if(func != undefined){
       obj = new (this.attach(builder, func))(new_element);
    }
```

with

```
    if(func != undefined){
       obj = func.bind(builder)(new_element) ;
    }
```

and it seems to work fine, negating the need for `attach` altogether.

Furthermore, you should consider adding functions to the prototype of `Builder` instead of to the instances of `builder`, this should reduce your memory foot-print.

Other than that:

- Run this through *JsHint* in JSFiddle, there are a few missing semicolons and a few dirty comparisons to `null` and `undefined`.
- Consider adding `'use strict'` at the start of `Builder`
- Just a thought, but I would default `el` to `document.body` if it is not provided

  ```
  this.root = el || document.body;
  ```
- In the same vein, in `append` I would expect an error if `el` is not set, instead you make silently the provided parameter the root. The name of that function does not match what it does

Everything else looks good and maintainable.